# how to override django save method to update some field dynamically?

Tags: python, django, orm

Here i have two models.In these models i want to make the value of `amount_to_pay` dynamic in `Ledger` model.For Example i have two different forms for these two models and while saving expense form if the user select the `payment_option` which comes from `ledger` model and gives some value for the `amount_to_pay` field  then if only `ledger.id` and `expense.payment_option_id` are same then the value of `amount_to_pay` in ledger model should be replaced with that value.how can i do it ?

**models.py**

```
     class Expense(models.Model):
        pay_from = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        payment_option = models.ForeignKey('Ledger', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        amount_to_pay = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        expense_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
        expense_type = models.ForeignKey(ExpenseType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        note = models.TextField()
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        slug = AutoSlugField(unique_with='id', populate_from='expense_type')

        def get_amount_to_pay(self):
            return self.amount_to_pay


    class Ledger(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        account_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        opening_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        amount_to_pay = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
        current_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        slug = AutoSlugField(unique_with='id', populate_from='name')

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
             self.amount_to_pay = Expense.get_amount_to_pay(self)

# here how can i save the amount_to_pay from expense form if the ledger.id and expense.payment_option.id matches??
#i got stuck here.           
 self.current_balance = self.opening_balance - self.amount_to_pay

            super(Ledger, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Solution One:

I think instead of changing in `Ledger` model, you should change in `Expense` model, like this:

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.payment_option.amount_to_pay = self.payment_option.amount_to_pay + self.amount_to_pay
       self.payment_option.save()
       super(Expense, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Solution Two:

But to be honest, **Solution One** does not seem good to me. Reason is that you are saving same data in 2 places(in both expense and ledger). Instead, it should be once, then the `amount_to_pay` value in `Ledger` should be calculated dynamically. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Ledger(...):

     @property
     def amount_to_pay(self):
         # I am using a property method to show the amount_to_pay value.
         # FYI: in this way, you need to remove amount_to_pay field from Ledger model
         return self.opening_balance - self.expense_set.all().aggregate(a_sum=Sum('amount_to_pay')).get('a_sum', 0)
```

In that way, with each ledger, the value `amount_to_pay` will be dynamically calculated at runtime. For example:

```
 for l in Ledger.objects.all():
     l.amount_to_pay
```

#### Solution Three:

If you are wary of making DB hits with each `l.amount_to_pay`(as it calculates amount_to_pay from DB dynamically) from previous solution, then you can always [**`annotate`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) the value. Like this:

For this solution, you need to change your `Expense` model and add a [**`related_name`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    pay_from = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment_option = models.ForeignKey('Ledger', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expenses')
```

Then use that `related_name` in query like this(FYI: You can't keep **`def amount_to_pay(...)`** method in *Ledger* model for the following usage example):

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField

ledgers = Ledger.objects.all().annotate(expense_sum=Sum('expenses__amount_to_pay')).annotate(amount_to_pay=ExpressionWrapper(F('opening_balance') - F('expense_sum'), output_field=IntegerField()))

# usage one
for l in ledgers:
   l.amount_to_pay

# usage two
ledgers.values('amount_to_pay')
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is you override the call in save method any way you have foreginkey.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #self.date_created = timezone.now()
        # YOUR LOGIC HERE
        super(YOUR_OVERRIDING_MODEL , self).save(*args, **kwargs
```

Comment: amount_to_pay and current_balance is required

Comment: `amount_to_pay = Expense.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['amount_to_pay_id'])`   print this value

Comment: `amount_to_pay_id` to `amount_to_pay`

Answer (score 0):

check if Ledger have child and then update it:

```
class Expense(models.Model):    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.payment_option.amount_to_pay = self.payment_option.amount_to_pay + self.amount_to_pay
                self.payment_option.save()
            super(Expense, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: self.ledger_payment_option.amount_to_pay = 1000 what it does ?? i want to save it dynamic .if only the user gives value from expense modelform and  the id of both payment_option and ledger matches then the value of amount_to_pay in ledger table should be replaced with that entered data by user

Comment: if you wan to update `Ledger.amount_to_pay` from Expense model you have answer.

Answer (score -1):

### Override save method and update some field dynamically in django

For my case i wanted to update done column in answer model dynamically when i comment on an answer it should return true instead of False. So in my example i am checking for whether  that column done which is boolean is False and if it's False,i change it's status to True using the answer object from Comment and then save the answer object,  see more about update vs insert fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codeAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    girAnswer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    firebaseToken = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.username, self.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.codeAnswer)

# So here i override the save method in the Comment model to do what i want as below.

class Comment(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey("Answer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False , related_name="comments")
    writerName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.writerName)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.answer.done is False:
            self.answer.done = True
            self.answer.save()
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it answers the question above thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29816327)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).